# Array comparison, get the rank of number

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I have a set of number, the purpose is to calculate the probability of permutation and i need to compare the outcome.

```
1|      974407      |
 |---------|--------|
2| 97440x  | x74407 |
3| 9744xx  | xx4407 |
4| 974xxx  | xxx407 |
5| 97xxxx  | xxxx07 |
```

This is the format of the information I want to compare. and it's in array format. The information is crawl from other website and the order cannot be changed.

```
$data = [974407,97440,74407,9744,4407,974,407,97,07]
```

I need to know the rank. For example:

```
974123 - rank 4
197400 - no rank
974123 - is not rank 5
```

**Update**

Thanks to mephisto123 for posting the sample of code, and the following is how i called it. I'm really not good at math and i not sure why it's returning -1 when i'm calling the URL.

```
http://localhost:8000/rank/974123
```

I need to get the ranking from the function also.

```
    public function theRank($value){
        $data = [974407,97440,74407,9744,4407,974,407,97,07];
        $rank = Helper::GetRank($data, $value);
        echo $value . " = " . $rank;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetRank($data, $value) 
{
    if ($value == $data[0]) return 1;
    $digits = strlen(strval($value));
    $len = sizeof($data);

    for ($i = 1, $div = 10, $mod = pow(10, $digits - 1); $i < $len; $i += 2, $div *= 10, $mod /= 10) {
        if ($data[$i] == intval($value / $div)) break;
        if ($data[$i + 1] == intval($value % $mod)) break;
    }
    if ($i >= $len) return -1;
    return ($i + 3) >> 1;
}
```

Comment: it's returning -1 when i input 974123 into the function. :( is it possible to get the rank?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is loop on the array and use the modulo and division  operator to get the different sets of numbers and then compare them to another array which holds the different kind of ranks to get the rank of that specific number.

For example 974123 / 1000 will get you 974 as outcome and you can compare it to an array which holds the different rank templates and get the position of that number which will constitute the rank.

Comment: Thanks to mephisto he written the code. however, i still couldn't get the rank from the function. is the code exactly demonstrating what you mean?